# How to write -webkit- in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, webkit

I need to change a property, which starts with `-webkit-`(and the other browser-specific statements), in Javascript. All of them start with dash. How am i supposed to write this?

In particular, the thing i need is `-webkit-user-select`. I know it should be something like `webkitUserSelect`, but no idea of what exactly.

Thanks

Comment: (The name of the real post, of which this one is duplicate, is not ment to be searched for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you write any property that can't be used with dot notation:

```
element.style['-webkit-user-select'] = 'none';
```